# how to call cvLoadImage in Scala?

Tags: scala, javacv

I would like to use javaCV in Scala, and have written the build.sbt according to instruction given here https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv). I am trying to run a Scala version of the sample smoother, and have written:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core._
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc._
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs._

object Face{

    def main(args: Array[String]){
       //IplImage image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg")
       //if(image == null){ 
           println("hello")
       //}
   }
}
```

The import statements alone does not cause any errors. However, when I uncomment I am not able to compile due to errors. Is my code correct? or is there some trick when using java code that I haven't respected? I also found someone mentioning that they can not initialise the class https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/issues/1 (and the issue should have been fixed).

```
[error] /Users/developer/Desktop/scala/face/face.scala:9: value image is not a member of object org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage
[error]         IplImage image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg")
[error]                  ^
[error] /Users/developer/Desktop/scala/face/face.scala:10: not found: value image
[error]         if(image == null){ 
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a scala syntax error. In Scala, you declare a value (a "variable") using either `val` (for an immutable value) or `var` (for an mutable value), followed by the name, then optionally the type, so your line:

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg") // Java declaration syntax
```

becomes:

```
val image: IplImage = cvLoadImage("test.jpg") // full Scala syntax
```

or just:

```
val image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg") // typically sufficient Scala syntax
```

Comment: thank you and sorry - I should have thought of that. I got to focused on the Java..

Comment: when that is corrected, I get this error  Class java.lang.AutoCloseable not found - continuing with a stub. That would be because they have made changes to the package content, right?

Comment: @stian I'm not sure - it might help to know where in your code you get this error. You should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

> `IplImage image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg")`

That's not how you declare a variable in Scala. It should be `val image = ...` or `val image: IplImage = ...`.